# Gridview second page not binding in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to bind student register number as in DataTable1 in Gridview1 with positions as in DataTable2 .
But, Gridview1 first page only bind, second page onwards not binding. I give my .net code , DB table structure and Gridview1 display below. If anybody give me solution, I will thankful to you.

### **C#.Net Code**

```
private void dgvHallSeating()
        {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt;

        DataTable dtSeatPositionsAssign = new DataTable();

        DataColumn col1;
        DataColumn col2;
        DataColumn col3;
        DataColumn col4;
        DataColumn col5;

        dt = new DataTable();
        col1 = new DataColumn("col1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col2 = new DataColumn("col2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col3 = new DataColumn("col3", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col4 = new DataColumn("col4", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col5 = new DataColumn("col5", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col1);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col2);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col3);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col4);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col5);

        Int32 SeatPositionColIndex = 0;
        Int32 SeatPositionRowIndex = 0;

        DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable2 = CMSBL.dtecSeatSlot1Positions();

        DataTable DataTable1 = CMSBL.rptecSeatSlot1Reports();

        int RegNoRowIndex = 0;
        int HallSeatPosition = 0;

        for (; RegNoRowIndex < 11; RegNoRowIndex++)
        {
            for (; HallSeatPosition < DataTable2.Rows.Count; )
            {
                SeatPositionColIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DataTable2.Rows[HallSeatPosition]["ecGridColumnIndex"]);
                SeatPositionColIndex = SeatPositionColIndex - 1;

                SeatPositionRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DataTable2.Rows[HallSeatPosition]["ecGridRowIndex"]);
                SeatPositionRowIndex = SeatPositionRowIndex - 1;

                dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows.Add();
                if (SeatPositionRowIndex >= dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows.Count || GridView1.Rows.Count <= 5)
                {
                    dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows.Add();
                }
                dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows[SeatPositionRowIndex][SeatPositionColIndex] = DataTable1.Rows[RegNoRowIndex][3].ToString();

                break;
            }
            HallSeatPosition++;
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dtSeatPositionsAssign;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

**

### DataTable1

**
[image]

### **Datatable2**

[image]

**

### Gridview1 Display

[image]